# How to control Faulhaber AES-4096 Motor by using ROS_CANopen?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I'd like to control (initialize and send can messages) to the Faulhaber motors.

I've downloaded the ros_canopen package and I've build it successfully in ubuntu kinetic OS.

I've run in cmd the following commands: 1)sudo modprobe peak_usb 2)sudo modprobe peak_pci 3)sudo modprobe pcan 4)sudo modprobe esd_usb2 5)sudo ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000 in the first cmd window.

the following command: 1) rosrun socketcan_bridge socketcan_bridge_node in a second cmd window

and: 1)rostopic echo /received_messages in a last cmd window.

I try to use the frames to initiate the motors. I'm not sure though how I can send the messages in the can.

I've tried: -cansend can0 (123#1122334455667788) can_id#data format for the frame but in the third cmd window the received message is not right.

In the data field I send the bytes in HEX, in the way I want the motors to receive them, but the data are returned differently. The motors aren't initiated.

So, here are my questions:

1. Are EDS/DCF files necessary for only the motor?
2. Can anyone guide me so that I can send the frame message correctly?
3. What would be and how could I send the header?

4)Is a mask already by default running? If so, how do I have to send the data to initiate the motor?

5)Finally, the frame.id="", I know is the default value, but shouldn't I receive the frame I sent?

Thank you!

Thank you in advance! :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340140/how-to-control-faulhaber-aes-4096-motor-by-using-ros_canopen?/) by [nz](https://answers.ros.org/users/50330/nz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-12-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-17**:\

> when this command was executed 'rosrun socketcan_interface socketcan_dump can0' errors popped out.

it would help readers here to know *which* particular errors you saw.

**Comment by [nz](https://answers.ros.org/users/50330/nz/) on 2019-12-17**:
@gvdhoorn the errors were:
ERROR: state=1 internal_error=0('OK') asio: system:0
ERROR: state=2 internal_error=0('OK') asio: system:0

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-17**:
This is not for me specifically. It's for people reading your question.

Please also copy-paste the errors *verbatim* into your original question. Use the `edit` button/link for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, this is just a misleading output from https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/blob/kinetic-devel/socketcan_interface/src/candump.cpp#L46

`ERROR` should better be `STATE` (I will [fix](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/pull/370) that!).

In the first first line

```
ERROR: state=1 internal_error=0('OK') asio: system:0
```

`state=1` means that the device was opened successfully.

And in the second line

```
ERROR: state=2 internal_error=0('OK') asio: system:0
```

the driver switches to ready and can therefore receive and transmit data.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2019-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nz](https://answers.ros.org/users/50330/nz/) on 2019-12-18**:
okey! thank you for your answer

**Comment by [nz](https://answers.ros.org/users/50330/nz/) on 2019-12-18**:
@Mathias could you please check my post again, as I've added some things and more specific questions?